# ImportError: libeccodes-8df36f07.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pygrib

I installed Python Pygrib and eccodes libraries.
When I import Pygrib I get error:

```
$ python -m pygrib selfcheck
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/mnt/c/Chantiers/repos/gcp-alim-process-gfs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygrib/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._pygrib import *
ImportError: libeccodes-8df36f07.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My OS :

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (oe-user@oe-host) (x86_64-msft-linux-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34.0.20200220) #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021
```

I think I have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH but I don't find libeccodes-8df36f07.so file on the filesystem.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried installing libeccodecs?

Comment: From what Ubuntu Package?